# Вывести значение выбраного option-а из selecta в js

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, alert

HTML:

```html
<select size="1" multiple name="класс[]">
  <option class="grade" value="5">5</option>
  <option class="grade" value="6">6</option>
  <option class="grade" value="7">7</option>
</select>
<input id="search" type="button" value="Искать">
```

Как найти `option`, который он выбрал, **но не выделял**? Например, если пользователь нажмёт на кнопку, вообще не трогая `select`? Для примера предлагаю вывести значение `option-а` в `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

У тега `select` есть специальное свойство - `.selectedOptions`. Это коллекция, которая содержит в себе все выбранные `option`.

```
const selectElem = document.querySelector('select');
const selectedOptions = selectElem.selectOptions;
for (let i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++) {
  alert(selectedOptions[i].innerText);
}
```

Подробнее: [документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions)

#### Update:

Можно получить список всех `option` с помощью `.options`. Все невыбранные можно получить примерно так:

```
const selectElem = document.querySelector('select');
const selectedOptions = selectElem.selectOptions;
const allOptions = selectELem.options;

const unselectedOptions = allOptions.filter(option => {
   return !selectedOptions.some(selectedOption => selectedOption === option);
});
```

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, свой ответ со внесёнными изменениями

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, ещё раз